# How do I connect remotely to an Ububtu Gnome desktop?

Tags: remote

I am running two PCs with Ububtu 14.04. I want to control one desktop remotely from the other. I have activated remote control on both computers. How shall I proceed? Do I have to install something? I am expecting it to work out of the box. Am I expecting too much?

Thanx

Comment: You want to connect through shell or you need graphic interface also?

Answer (score 0):

You can do remote control regardless the version of Ubuntu you use. That depends on the Default Display Manager you have and the protocol XDMCP. You can find how to proceed on the ubuntu's wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/xdmcp